# What are body parts used for?

Tags: salt-and-sanctuary

I just started playing this game and sometimes slain enemies drop body parts. I have 3 kinds of ears and their description says that these can be used as  "transmutation material" or exchanged with leaders. So, what is transmutation and what are the benefits of exchanging "ears" with leaders? 
I'm assuming that I'll be able to find leaders in sanctuaries lying ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about those ears like material for crafting and exchanging with NPC's.

The transmution part is explained in the Wiki:
http://saltandsanctuary.wiki.fextralife.com/Transmutation